# codimension of complementary subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

X is a linear space, and Y and N are complementary subspaces of X, i.e. $X = N \oplus Y.$ Show that when N has finite codimension, $dim Y = codim N$.

This is an exercise from Lax's functional analysis. My question is that why it supposes N has finite codimension.

Comment: If you define the codimension as the of the quotient $X/N$ then $Y$ is isomorphic to this quotient and hence has the same Dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I knew that before. I don't know why N must have finite codimension.@Jochen

Comment: This also holds for infinite codimension.

Comment: @Jochen You enlightening comment has helped me solve my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703052/let-l-be-a-topological-complement-of-g-is-dim-g-operatornamecodim). Thank you so much!