# Let $L$ be a (topological) complement of $G$. Is $\dim G = \operatorname{codim} L$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cardinals

Two [Hamel bases](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition) of the same vector space have [the same cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/proof-that-two-bases-of-a-vector-space-have-the-same-cardinality-in-the-infinite), so we define the dimension of a vector space as the [cardinality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition) of one of its [Hamel basis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hamel_basis#Definition).

Could you confirm if my below understanding is fine?

---

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Let $G$ be a closed subspace of $E$. Let $L$ be a (topological) complement of $G$, i.e., $L$ is a closed subspace of $E$ such that $G\cap L = \{0\}$ and $G+L=E$.

- By [cardinal arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131212/overview-of-basic-results-on-cardinal-arithmetic), $\dim G +\dim L = \dim E$. This identity implies a result (for Hilbert spaces) in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766613/proof-sum-of-dimension-of-orthogonal-complement-and-vector-subspace) question.
- By [rank-nullity theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752056/does-the-rank-nullity-theorem-hold-for-infinite-dimensional-v?rq=1), $\operatorname{codim} L + \dim L = \dim E$.

Then $\dim G = \operatorname{codim} L$ follows from below **Lemma**.

> **Lemma** Let $A, B, C$ be non-empty sets. If $|A|+|B| = |A|+|C|$, then $|B|=|C|$. Here $|A|$ is the cardinality of $A$.

---

As indicated in a comment, above **Lemma** is not true. I would like to ask if $\dim G = \operatorname{codim} L$ still holds.

Comment: The Lemma does not hold for infinite cardinalities. For example, if $A$ is infinite, $|B|=1$ and $|C|=2$, then $|A|+|B| = |A| = |A|+|C|$ but $|B| \neq |C|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736212/codimension-of-complementary-subspace#comment7682352_3736212) enlightening comment by Jochen, I have come up with below proof.

---

We need some results from Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Theorem 2.10.** Let $E$ be a Banach space. Assume that $G$ and $L$ are two closed linear subspaces such that $G+L$ is closed. Then there exists a constant $C \geq 0$ such that
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \text { every } z \in G+L \text { admits a decomposition of the form } \\
> z=x+y \text { with } x \in G, y \in L,\|x\| \leq C\|z\| \text { and }\|y\| \leq C\|z\|
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
>
> **Definition.** Let $G \subset E$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $E$. A subspace $L \subset E$ is said to be a topological complement or simply a complement of $G$ if
> (i) $L$ is closed,
> (ii) $G \cap L=\{0\}$ and $G+L=E$.
>
> We shall also say that $G$ and $L$ are complementary subspaces of $E$. If this holds, then every $z \in E$ may be uniquely written as $z=x+y$ with $x \in G$ and $y \in L$. It follows from **Theorem 2.10** that the projection operators $z \mapsto x$ and $z \mapsto y$ are continuous linear operators. (That property could also serve as a definition of complementary subspaces.)

Let $\pi:E \to G$ be the continuous linear projection map defined in above paragraph. Then $\pi$ is surjective homomorphism such that $\ker \pi = L$. By [first isomorphism theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(groups)) for groups,
$$
\operatorname{im} \pi \cong E / \ker \pi.
$$

It follows that $G \cong E/L$ and thus $\dim G = \dim (E/L) =: \operatorname{codim} L$.